# Having MenuItem inside NavDropdown have a link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dashboard, react-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to ReactJS and Bootstrap, so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I downloaded a template online and I have a dropdown in the navbar of my app. For reference, here is what the dropdown looks like:

[image: Dropdown Navbar]

What I want is for each `<MenuItem>` (The 'API Service #' buttons) to send me to a different link. I have tried tweaking around a little bit and this is what I got so far:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Nav, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";

class AdminNavbarLinks extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={2} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.1} href="/serviceone">
              API Service 1
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.2} href="/servicetwo">
              API Service 2
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.3} href="/servicethree">
              API Service 3
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.4} href="/servicefour">
              API Service 4
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.5} href="/servicefive">
              API Service 5
            </MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          //Other NavDropdowns
        </Nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminNavbarLinks;
```

What this code currently does is sends you to the link that corresponds to each `href`, but then immediately sends you to the default page of the app, which is `/dashboard` (An example is if I click on the "API Service 3" button on the dropdown, it sends me to "#/servicethree", but then immediately sends me back to "#/dashboard"). I'm curious as to why it reverts me back to the default page? Any help would be appreciated, since i'm not quite sure how to make these MenuItems have a link. I can provide more code if necessary.

**EDIT:**

Here is the updated `AdminNavbarLinks` file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Nav, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from "react-router-dom";

class AdminNavbarLinks extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={2} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">

            <Link to="/serviceone">
              <MenuItem eventKey={2.1} href="/serviceone">
                API Service 1
              </MenuItem>
            </Link>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.2} href="/servicetwo">
              API Service 2
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.3} href="/servicethree">
              API Service 3
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.4} href="/servicefour">
              API Service 4
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey={2.5} href="/servicefive">
              API Service 5
            </MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          //Other NavDropdowns
        </Nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminNavbarLinks;
```

And now here is the main file `index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "components/Navbars/AdminNavbarLinks.jsx";
import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard.jsx";
import ServiceOne from "views/ServiceOne.jsx";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./assets/css/animate.min.css";
import "./assets/sass/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss?v=1.3.0";
import "./assets/css/demo.css";
import "./assets/css/pe-icon-7-stroke.css";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} exact />
      <Route path="/serviceone" component={ServiceOne} exact />
    </Switch>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**EDIT #2**

Solution found. See my answer below.

Comment: Are you using react-router?

Comment: No, i'm not importing anything from React Router

Comment: Sorry i meant react-router-dom. That's what you need to actually move around from one component to another :)

Comment: Thank you. I checked some of the code from the other files in the template and indeed they use `import { ... } from "react-router-dom"`. How would I incorporate a `<Link to=` tag inside the `<MenuItems>`? Once again i'm just learning about Bootstrap and ReactJS so i'm still trying to figure out where the jsx tags get put correctly.

Comment: You would nest the MenuItem inside the Link tag. Here I'll show you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this to work. All I did was change some properties of the `<Link to` tag. Here is how `AdminNavbarLinks` now looks:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Nav, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class AdminNavbarLinks extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav>
          <NavDropdown title="Services" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <MenuItem>
             <NavLink
                      to="/admin/serviceone"
                      className="nav-link"
                      activeClassName="active"
                    >
                     API Service 1
                    </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
             <NavLink
                      to="/admin/servicetwo"
                      className="nav-link"
                      activeClassName="active"
                    >
                     API Service 2
                    </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>
             <NavLink
                      to="/admin/servicethree"
                      className="nav-link"
                      activeClassName="active"
                    >
                     API Service 3
                    </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>
             <NavLink
                      to="/admin/servicefour"
                      className="nav-link"
                      activeClassName="active"
                    >
                     API Service 4
                    </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem>
             <NavLink
                      to="/admin/servicefive"
                      className="nav-link"
                      activeClassName="active"
                    >
                     API Service 5
                    </NavLink>
            </MenuItem>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          //Other NavDropdowns
        </Nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminNavbarLinks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate react-router-dom to navigate across components in your React application.

Simply nest the `MenuItems` in a `Link` tag. And in each `Link` tag, you define the `to` property with the path that you want to navigate to. This will end up displaying a completely different component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Nav, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from "react-bootstrap";

class AdminNavbarLinks extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav>
          <NavDropdown eventKey={2} title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
            <Link to="/serviceone">
               <MenuItem eventKey={2.1}>
                 API Service 1
              </MenuItem>
            </Link>
            ...repeat for others
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          //Other NavDropdowns
        </Nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AdminNavbarLinks;
```

You would also have to define your `Routes` in your main application, to complete the configuration.

Something like this would suffice:

### App.js

```
import React from "react"
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-dom
import Navbar from "whatever path this"
import Home from "./whatever path this"
import ServiceOne from "./whatever path this"

const App = () => {
  return(
     <BrowserRouter>
         <Navbar/>
         <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
            <Route path="/serviceone" component={ServiceOne} exact/>
         </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
  )

}
```

In the above we've defined some very basic routing for your App. I'm assuming your `Navbar` actually has the `AdminNavbarLinks` component inside it. From there you just click a `Link` with a matching url path to the `Routes` you defined.

Comment: I implemented the code as you said but I still get the same error, in that it just immediately redirects me to the `/dashboard` page. I edited my post to reflect the code I have. Should I add the new `<Route>` tags somewhere else?

Comment: @Cizox try removing the href that you defined for the MenuItem. My guess is that its still getting clicked.

Comment: Nope, now it wont send me to the webpage at all